# MySQL- load columns into a previous table that match with the existent data

Tags: mysql, csv, load, match

I am having issues making updates with the data.  So here is the thing: 
1) I loaded into mysql dumps of data corresponding to daily climate data. I have 18 tables with daily data (one table per parameter). My goal is to merge them into one single table.

**Table 1**

```
station| dayOfYear| temp|

1|  20010101|   2|

2|  20010101|   3|

3|  20010101|   4|

1|  20010102|   3|

2|  20010102|   4|

3|  20010102|   4|
```

**Table 2**

```
station|    dayOfYear|  humidity

1|  20010101|   20|

2|  20010101|   35|

3|  20010101|   100|

1|  20010102|   14|

2|  20010102|   40|

3|  20010102|   80|
```

2)As you can see in the example *(table1 and table2)*, all of those tables shared **"station" and "dayOfYear"** column.  Therefore,

3) My initial plan was that once having every dump uploaded I would update in my "TargetTable" (I had previously created and it contains one column per parameter and the shared columns **"Station" and "dayOfYear"**)with each one of the dumps, so at the end I would have one table with the data per day per paremeter.
My plan did not work, I have more than 2 millions of rows, the query lasted hours running and at the end connection went lost. So I would get smth like this:

**TargetTable**

station|dayOfYear|temp|humidity

1|  20010101|   2|  20

2|  20010101|   3|  35

3|  20010101|   4|  100

1|  20010102|   3|  14

2|  20010102|   4|  40

3|  20010102|   4|  80

Since my plan (get the TargeTable with a join) did not work,  I am wondering if its possible in mysql to add the columns to the "Targettable" since the begining, at the time of uploading the csv's.

Something like:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'C:/Daily/temp.csv'
INTO TABLE TargetTable
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 rows( stn, dayOfYear, temp, humidity);

 LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'C:/Daily/hum.csv'
INTO TABLE TargetTable
SET
  humidity= ...?? **what would come here??**
```

Do you know how to do it? Do you have any other suggestion of how to handle this problem.  *JFYI.  I already modified the time for running queries.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `on duplicate` mysql feature. Here you can implement it:

**1-Preparetion**

a] create a temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTarget LIKE TargetTable;
```

b] alter TargetTable keys

```
ALTER TABLE TargetTable 
DROP PRIMARY KEY
ADD PRIMARY KEY (stn, dayOfYear);
```

**2-Routines**

a] insert temperature data into real target table (as you already did)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'C:/Daily/temp.csv'
INTO TABLE TargetTable
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 rows( stn, dayOfYear, temp, humidity);
```

b] insert humidity data into `tmp` table first

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'C:/Daily/hum.csv'
INTO TABLE tmpTarget
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 rows( stn, dayOfYear, temp, humidity) set @temp=null;
```

c] update or insert data to the real target table from the tmp table

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT * FROM tmpTarget
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE humidity = VALUES(humidity);
```

d] Truncate the tmp table

```
TRUNCATE tmpTarget;
```

Comment: You are a GENIOUS!! Just as an addition, In the step 2b is necessary to add LOAD DATA LOCAL
INFILE 'C:/Daily/hum.csv'
INTO TABLE tmpTarget
CHARACTER SET UTF8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 rows( stn, dayOfYear, temp, humidity) set @temp=null; otherwise is putting the humidity in the temp column,  Thanks

Comment: @Monitotier: Good to help ;) 
I re-edited [2b] according your testing. 
A little `up-vote` or `accepting my answer` will be very welcome if you were satisfied with it.

Comment: I don't have power to give you a vote!! so sad :( As long as I get enough power I will do it :) ... I accepted your perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

I see another post who asked like you.
The method to improve speed is Insert column row by row with some custom script. 
On another hand. 
FWIW the following steps caused a huge speedup of LOAD DATA INFILE:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-UNCOMMITTED';
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
#LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE....
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-REPEATABLE';
```

More info at [Best practices for importing large CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166506/best-practices-for-importing-large-csv-files)

Comment: thanks! I will go through this you have posted. I was googling a lot, but since I did not how to elaborate the question, I was not even closed to get what you have suggested. Thanks, I will go check

Comment: I have checked what you kindly suggested, but those lines help to improve the loading. My problem was not loading. My problem was performing the join between tables.  That's why I was asking if there was a way in the loading: "to create a loading query where the table I want to add, matches with the pre-loaded table in two of its columns _(station and Day of the year)_, then add the third/rest of the cvs table to the pre-load(targetTable).  _Seems that I did not explain it correctly._